# What is wrong with my Grid class?

Tags: java, processing

I am trying to create a Grid class to arrange elements the screen on rows and cols. The methods cellXCenter() and cellYCenter() are supposed to return the coordinates for a given i cell on the grid.

When running this code, which is supposed to draw an ellipse inside each grid cell, only the last element is given the correct coordinates.

What I am doing wrong?

```
Grid grid;

int columns = 3;
int rows = 2;



 void setup() {
   size(900,600);
   background(0);
   grid = new Grid(columns,rows);
   fill(255,0,0);
   for (int i = 0 ; i < columns * rows; i++) {
     ellipse(grid.cellXCenter(i+1),grid.cellYCenter(i+1),100,100); 
   }

 }


class Grid {
  //grid width, height, number of columns, number of rows
  int gw; 
  int gh; 
  int cols; 
  int rows;

  int cells; //total de celdas desde 1
  float cellWidth;
  float cellHeight;

  Grid(int cols_, int rows_) {
   gw = width;
   gh = height;
   cols = cols_; 
   rows = rows_; 
   cells = rows * cols;
   cellWidth = gw / cols;
   cellHeight = gh / rows;
  }

  int rowPos(int index_) {   
    //all index arguments one based
    float i = index_; 
    int position = (int)Math.ceil(i/cols);    
    return position;
  }

  int colPos(int index_) {
    int i = index_;
    int position = i - (cols * (rowPos(i) -1));
    return position;    
  }

  float cellX(int index_) {
    int i = index_;
    float xPos = gw * (colPos(i)/cols);
    return xPos;
  }

  float cellXCenter(int index_) {
    int i = index_;
    float xCenterPos = cellX(i) - cellWidth/2;
    return xCenterPos;    
  }

  float cellY(int index_) {
    int i = index_;
    float yPos = gh * (rowPos(i)/rows);
    return yPos;
  }

  float cellYCenter(int index_) {
    int i = index_;
    float yCenterPos = cellY(i) - cellHeight/2;
    return yCenterPos;
  }

}
```

Comment: Code is hard to read, mixing local and external variables. Hard to check that types ares used properly etc...

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some debugging. I'd start out by printing out the position of every cell:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < columns * rows; i++) {
   println(grid.cellXCenter(i+1) + ", " + grid.cellYCenter(i+1));
   ellipse(grid.cellXCenter(i+1),grid.cellYCenter(i+1),10,10); 
}
```

This prints out:

```
-150.0, -150.0
-150.0, -150.0
750.0, -150.0
-150.0, 450.0
-150.0, 450.0
750.0, 450.0
```

So you can see that all but one of your cells have negative coordinates, which cause them to be drawn off the edges of the window.

Now you need to keep debugging to figure out why these values are negative. Add more print statements to see exactly what's going on in your code, and find the line that's not behaving how you expect.

When you get it narrowed down to just a few lines that aren't behaving how you expect, then you can post a more specific question along with an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck.